# How is the following output generated?

Tags: c

I seem to be having a problem how the following code generates output:

```
main()
{
    int k = 35 ; 
    printf ( "\n%d %d %d", k == 35, k = 50, k > 40 ) ;
}
```

Since `k` is initialized to 35, then the first relation `k==35` must evaluate to true, hence a non-zero value, also for the third condition, as the value of `k` has been changed to `50`, so it must also be true, again a non-zero value but on execution, the program gives output as `0 50 0`. Could anyone explain the reason behind this?

Comment: The order of evaluation for your arguments is undefined so you're invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @tangrs Undefined or merely *unspecified* behavior?

Comment: Actually the above problem is from 'Let us C' by Yashwant Kanetkar. Pg 80, Problem A(g).

Comment: And how do I decide in which order the arguments get evaluated, in similar cases? @Jens

Comment: @tamojitMaiti You don't. You can't know. (Your best bet is to look at the generated assembly, but it may vary from compilation to compilation. Or from run to run.)

Comment: @tamojitMaiti The correct way to program is to not depend on unspecified behavior. This is always easy: use separate printf statements when you need to modify one of the arguments. The aim must be to make your programs behave the same on any system, with any compiler, any options. Everything else is a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments will `not` always evaluate in `left to right order`.

So avoid writing codes whose output is not sure. If you want to write such a program please use three different **printf()** to print all the three arguments.

Answer (score 4):

The function arguments can be evaluated in any order. Your compiler has chosen to evaluate the arguments from right to left, i.e.

```
main()
{
    int k = 35 ; 
    int result_first = (k > 40);  // 0
    int result_second = (k = 50); // 50
    int result_third = (k == 35); // 0
    printf ( "\n%d %d %d", result_third, result_second, result_first ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Function argument have no order of evaluation. It is unspecified and compiler can evaluate it any order as wish.

Comment: Nope, the conditional operator will return only 0 or 1

Comment: Yes! A candidate result

Comment: @silentboy: Output of “35 50 50” would be conforming (to the C standard), because the code both modifies and accesses `k` with indeterminate sequencing. Per C 2011 6.5 2, the C standard does not define the behavior required in this case; any behavior is permitted.

Comment: @eric There was a debate in a local programming group about it. You are right! But we tested it in some different compiler on different machine with different optimization level. But no one found a surpraising result.

Answer (score 1):

initializing the values or updating the values in printf statement is a bad practice.

you could instead take few other variables and initiate them with those resulting values an use them.

or if you want to print them, you can use three different `printf` statements as shown

```
printf("%d ",k==35);
printf("%d ",k=50);
printf("%d\n",k>40);
```

as evaluation of those arguments may not always be in the order you declared.